# Can parallelism cause 100% CPU usage?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I realize this question is kind of vague, but I'm hoping someone can point me in a direction of things to look at.

My problem is that I have a query within a program that is driving the CPUs on my SQL Server to 100%.  I think that the problem is related to parallelism, but I don't know how to confirm my suspicion, or the best way to fix the problem.

The query in question spent about 20 minutes running the server at 100% CPU, at which point I killed the query.  I used `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` to look at the query execution plan.  There are no index scans.  The index operations are all seeks.  I'm confident that my indexes are well chosen for this query.  I do see a lot of parallelism going on within the query.

For comparison, I tried running the same query in the query window in Management Studio.  The query runs in no more than a few seconds, and the Display Estimated Execution Plan button gives me a different execution plan.  One of the differences in this execution plan is that there is no parallelism.

[Here is a link to the query execution plan for the bad query.](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByNDh3miQ)  One thing which is looks like a problem is the clustered index seek on `PS_TRANSACTION_INV` with a predicate on `PS_TRANSACTION_INV.BUSINESS_UNIT` (all the way to the right in the execution plan) shows 1 estimated row.  All but a few hundred rows have the value `TRUS1` and the rest of the rows have the value `TRCN1`.  The table has about 15 million rows and uses about 22 GB (so the rows are pretty large).  I did `DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS` for the table's clustered index, and the statistics look correct (as shown below).  The execution plan also has an estimated row size of 54 B, which is wrong.  The true row size is larger.

[image]

However, even with a bad execution plan, I don't understand how this query could run for 24+ hours without finishing.

Looking at `sys.sysprocesses`, I can see that the last wait type is `SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD`.

[Here is a link to the query execution plan for the good query.](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ry20hhQiQ)

My server has 8 CPUs and 24 GB of memory.  The query itself returns about 27,000 rows, so it should be well within the capability of the server to execute this quickly.  This program has been running for years with no problems, so I think something must have changed about the execution plan.  My server's DOP is 64.

Am I right in thinking that the problem is likely related to parallelism?  If so, how could that be causing a query that should run in a second or two to use 100% of the CPU for over 20 minutes and still not finish?

EDIT: In the execution plan for the bad query, I found that one of the steps is doing an index seek on a field where it should ideally do a clustered index seek.  The index seek is on a table that has about 20,000,000 rows, but the indexed field has high selectivity.  That index seek feeds into a nested loop (with parallelism) in the query plan.  I still think that the problem is in some way related to the parallelism.

For reference, I can run a `SELECT` on that table using the nonclustered index, and the query takes a few seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first question is what wait types did you see?

Second, how is your server set up (Maybe run [sp_Blitz](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/) and give us the output `sp_Blitz @OutputType = ‘markdown’, @CheckServerInfo = 1`)?

Third, is there anything else running, causing the bottleneck? Maybe start with [sp_BlitzFirst](https://www.brentozar.com/askbrent/) or [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/) to see what's going on.

> Can parallelism cause 100% CPU usage?

Sure can. [Brent wrote a query to do just this thing](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/09/one-hundred-percent-cpu/). Or, at least, he uses `MAXDOP 0` to ensure it happens, faster?

> For comparison, I tried running the same query in the query window in
>   Management Studio. The query runs in no more than a few seconds, and
>   the Display Estimated Execution Plan button gives me a different
>   execution plan

I don't work for Brent, [but he talks about this too.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/07/comparing-estimated-actual-execution-plans-sql-server/). You need to use the actual execution plan, not the estimated. [Adding it here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/), and including the link in your post is helpful. Also, you need to determine if the application is using a cached procedure plan, or if they are both using new plans. You can use `option(recompile)` to force a new plan and compare apples to apples (but like red delicious to granny smith which is better than apples to oranges)

> The query itself returns about 27,000 rows, so it should be well
>   within the capability of the server to execute this quickly.

The *final* number of rows being this small shouldn't be a measure of why it's performing poorly. Somewhere in the N number of joins there could be millions of rows being pulled back before the final predicate  is evaluated. This is where the actual execution plan would show you bottlenecks.

> My server's DOP is 64

Seems high, but you didn't tell us everything about how many cores you are running. Luckily, [Microsoft has good guidance on this.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2806535/recommendations-and-guidelines-for-the-max-degree-of-parallelism-confi). Before you go changing it at the server level, add a query hint to the bottom of your query... `option(maxdop 8)`. Also, I'd expect to see `CXPACKET` waits if it was parallelism. [Here's a video on that.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/08/what-is-the-cxpacket-wait-type-and-how-do-you-reduce-it/).

Lastly, remember that [query optimization is hard](https://youtu.be/RQfJkNqmHB4), even for the server. Granted this isn't the case for you since your application is taking forever, and SSMS returns the data fast, which is where I'd expect to see `ASYNC_NETWORK_IO` waits or something.

Comment: I updated my question with the execution plan for the good version of the query and the bad version of the query.

Comment: The last wait type is `SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD`

Comment: As you probably researched, SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD is (or can be, but in your case most likely is) related to your high CPU usage. I'm still looking at your execution plans

Comment: Ok off the top I can see that's an estimated execution plan for the bad query. One guess would be if I saw the actual execution plan, we could see a large difference in the estimated and actual rows from parameter sniffing. Since the query takes so long to run... we can try a few things. First, add `with recompile` to the top of the stored procedure or query running this code. This will ensure SQL Server doesn't use a plan from cache with the cached parameters (`@P3 = '(4118263.)', @P2 = 'TRCN1', @P1 = 'FIN'`). See if that helps the performance from the application.

Comment: Also, I would add the `OPTION(MAXDOP 8)` hint as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Unfortunately this query is written in a language that doesn't let me add query hints (I know; it's stupid but there's nothing I can do about it).  I have run into problems with parameter sniffing with stored procedures before, which caused queries that normally take a second to run take so long to run that I got annoyed and cancelled them.  I've been able to fix similar issues to this before by using `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`, but again this language doesn't let me do that.

Comment: The program that is having this problem uses set processing, so it's constantly clearing and repopulating a series of temporary tables (they're used for temporary data, but the tables themselves are real tables, not SQL Server temp tables).  From what I've been able to tell so far, the program does update index statistics while it's running, but I'll keep looking and see if it misses some tables during its statistics updates.

Comment: To elaborate, @P2 is set to what it should be, given what you said about those rows. In fact, since 99% of your rows `TRCN1`, you can optimize for that value as well via `option (optimize for @P2 = 'TRCN1')` but that's not going to affect this current query if it's using that estimated plan. I would just use that so you don't get a *bad* plan in the future... and i just saw you comment about query hints... bummer

Comment: I can't speak to the program of course, but you can be sure you have [auto update statistics on](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2766/sql-server-auto-update-and-auto-create-statistics-options/) on the SQL Server side. Seems like the problem may not rest with SQL Server, but with the application? Hard to see it all from here of course.

Comment: Lo and behold Auto Update Statistics is off.  I'll turn it on and monitor this process and see if it gets better.  Thanks a lot of the suggestion.  I'll be really happy if that turns out to be it (and also feel a little silly).

Comment: well a lot of rows will need to be updated / inserted or deleted. Not as many as the old algorithm, but you could speed this up by manually updating statistics on your tables during nightly maintenance. Remember that rebuilding an index also updates its statistics so no need to do both if you have maintenance that does that. Good luck!